# JavaScript background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, background

Guessing this will be a real easy fix for someone with the know-how. I am still learning JavaScript and I'm always trying to learn more.

I currently have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$("#background").fullBg();
});
</script>
```

This works fine. at the moment #background is:

```
<img src="images/background.jpg" alt="" id="background" />
```

However I want to be able to put the background in as a div background and not just an image.

How do I change the script above so that the function applies to the background-image of a div which will be set in CSS instead of pointing to the img tag as it currently does?

I have tried to search the internet for a solution; however I am not good enough at JS yet to word my search correctly to find what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my description is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.css()` is what you're looking for (this example uses jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#background").css({
        "background-image" : "url(images/background.jpg);",
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I believe that i need the .fullBg() for another script. Can i have it as you have posted but with ..fullBg() instead of .css ?

Comment: http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/ this is the jquery plugin which i believe uses .fullBg()

Comment: Well, you could use the CSS3 approach and use `background-size:cover` in your CSS, eliminating the need to use the plugin. Or, you could modify it to add a CSS class instead of creating an img.

Comment: I am guessing that editing the Jquery is going to be very difficult for me, so that probably rules that option out. Do you think i should be concerned about browser support for css3?

Comment: You could use an IF statement for browsers that don't support CSS3, and could fall back to using the script.

Comment: Just tested out the background-size:cover option. This stretches the size of the image. The script keeps the original aspect ratio of the image. So its not really going to work as a replacement :(

Comment: New idea: Keep the current script, but give it a `z-index` of `-1`. Ex.) http://jsfiddle.net/GHmz7/4/

Comment: That didnt seem to work. I think what would help me would be the opposite of <noscript> Then i will only display the image if javascript is enabled. Else there will be the standard css background. How do i detect is javascript is enabled?

Comment: I used document.write which has achieved my goal to a certain extend. Anyone not using JS will just have to have a lesser experience until i know enough to make it work for everyone lol.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to assign a css property to the DIV.
Then you should use .css('propertyName', 'value').
You can find the documentation at [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using ([fullBg](http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/)) was designed to work with img elements, not background images. Why do you even need a div? If you style the img with CSS as the plugin docs suggests, the outcome will be the same.

Comment: The basics of my need for a solution is that if JavaScript is switched off in the browser then the img is displayed as an image and not a background. It means that the website becomes almost un-useable. The image is very large so the user would need to scroll along way down to even see the first DIV. Can you think of an alternative?

Comment: You could hide the image on your CSS (`display: none`), then use jQuery `.show()` method to display it on page load. So if js is disabled, there would be no bg image (which is better than a huge image on the user's way).